# Badly-formed histogram causes bad estimates on Nested Loop

Tags: query-performance, sql-server-2016, statistics, database-internals, cardinality-estimates

We have a query on a SQL Server 2016 SP2 CU12 Enterprise where the Query Optimizer estimates that only 1 row would come out of the *Nested Loops Join* operator, in reality 108501 rows came back. This caused that the `Sort` operator spilled to TempDB.

The estimates on the inner (index seek) and outer input (index seek) of the Nested Loops Join are correct.

I added trace flags 2363 (Selectivity Computation) and 3604 (redirect the output to the messages window) and here I found that there was a badly-formed histogram:

> ```
> Plan for computation:
>
>   CSelCalcExpressionComparedToExpression( QCOL: [Object1].Column1 x_cmpEq QCOL: [Object3].Column18 )
>
> Loaded histogram for column QCOL: [Object1].Column1 from stats with id 1  *** WARNING: badly-formed histogram ***
>
> Loaded histogram for column QCOL: [Object3].Column18 from stats with id 9
>
> Selectivity: 1.07973e-009
>
> Stats collection generated: 
>
>   CStCollJoin(ID=4, CARD=1 x_jtLeftSemi)
>
>       CStCollBaseTable(ID=1, CARD=5.01133e+007 TBL: Schema1.Table2 AS TBL: AA)
>
>       CStCollFilter(ID=3, CARD=108210)
>
>           CStCollBaseTable(ID=2, CARD=2.00511e+006 TBL: Schema1.Table1 AS TBL: A)
>
> End selectivity computation
> ```

Above is only a part of the output, the full text can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YNpzJdMr8XRg39YHWXG6ZrF5Gn1eVL5gssTvVFtVGdU/edit?usp=sharing)

When I updated the badly-formed histogram with fullscan the estimates are correct (without fullscan this issue is not resolved).

But as soon as one record is inserted in the table, the histogram is badly-formed again.

The query plan (with badly-formed histogram) can be found [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkLdWeBXP) and [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkJCTeS7v) you can find the query plan after update statistics.

No query optimizer fixes are enabled.
When I enable the original cardinality estimator for this query, using trace flag 9481, I'm getting the same query plan as after update statistics.

What can cause the badly-formed histogram?

Is there a way to solve this issue?

I tried the `PERSIST_SAMPLE_PERCENT` option but it didn't make a difference, the histogram gets also badly-formed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What can cause the badly-formed histogram?

This is a bug of course. It occurs when SQL Server scales the inexact histogram and encounters a unique column with apparently more than one value per key. This was [partially addressed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3202425/improvement-improves-the-query-performance-for-sql-server-2016-by-chan) for SQL Server 2016, but it seems to me the full fix is only present on SQL Server 2017 (I tested on CU21).

> Is there a way to solve this issue?

Use `FULLSCAN` statistics, the original CE, upgrade to SQL Server 2017, or wait for the full fix to be back-ported.

#### Demo

Using my standard Numbers table creation script:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Numbers;
GO
-- Itzik Ben-Gan's row generator
WITH
  L0   AS (SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
  L1   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
  L2   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
  L3   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
  L4   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
  L5   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
  Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS n FROM L5)
SELECT
    -- Destination column type integer NOT NULL
    ISNULL(CONVERT(integer, N.n), 0) AS n
INTO dbo.Numbers
FROM Nums AS N
WHERE N.n >= 1
AND N.n <= 10 * 1000 * 1000
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Numbers
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Numbers_n
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (n)
WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON, MAXDOP = 1, FILLFACTOR = 100);
```

Update the statistics to be sampled:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.Numbers;
```

Trivial query (request an estimated plan only):

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Numbers AS N1
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.Numbers AS N2
    WHERE N2.n = N1.n
)
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 3604, QUERYTRACEON 2363);
```

The trace output includes:

```
Begin selectivity computation

Input tree:

  LogOp_LeftSemiJoin
      CStCollBaseTable(ID=1, CARD=1e+007 TBL: dbo.Numbers AS TBL: N1)
      CStCollBaseTable(ID=2, CARD=1e+007 TBL: dbo.Numbers AS TBL: N2)
      ScaOp_Comp x_cmpEq
          ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [N2].n
          ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [N1].n

Plan for computation:
  CSelCalcExpressionComparedToExpression( QCOL: [N1].n x_cmpEq QCOL: [N2].n )

Loaded histogram for column QCOL: [N1].n from stats with id 1
    *** WARNING: badly-formed histogram ***

Selectivity: 1
```

Validated on Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU14).

The statistics histogram obtained via:

```
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS 
    (Numbers, [PK_Numbers_n])
    WITH HISTOGRAM;
```

has entries like:

[image: 2016 histogram]

on SQL Server 2017 the histogram is:

[image: 2017 histogram]

Note the `EQ_ROWS` steps are pre-scaled rather than relying on the CE to do it.