# Statistics histogram AVG_RANGE_ROWS discrepancy

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, statistics

According to MS docs, the description for `AVG_RANGE_ROWS` is:

> Average number of rows with duplicate column values within a histogram step, excluding the upper bound. When DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS is greater than 0, AVG_RANGE_ROWS is calculated by dividing RANGE_ROWS by DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS. When DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS is 0, AVG_RANGE_ROWS returns 1 for the histogram step.

I'm looking at the last line and if that is indeed the case, I'm curious to know why I'm seeing a value for `AVG_RANGE_ROWS` that is not equals `1` when `DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS` is `0` in the histogram steps.

[image: stats_histogram]

The statistic in question is a column stat created by SQL Server when the auto create statistics option is turned on. I'm on an older version of the database, but on the latest patch - SQL Server 2014 SP3, CU4+GDR (12.0.6372.1).

It is a bit unfortunate that we almost had a meltdown last week because of a sub-optimal query plan. The end result result was large scans and bloated memory grants. Resampling the statistic with a higher percent value sort of resolved the issue for us for the time being but I'm mostly curious to know if there are exceptions around the initial statement or a known issue (perhaps addressed using a trace flag?) and how do I prevent this from happening again for auto created stats where we have no control over the sampling size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described in answer to [Badly-formed histogram causes bad estimates on Nested Loop](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/270270/badly-formed-histogram-causes-bad-estimates-on-nested-loop) there has been a change to the way sampled statistics are calculated and stored, more particularly when scaling is applied.

As a side-effect, the value for `DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS` in your case is a fraction between 0 and 1 (980.235 / 386212.6 = 0.002538071). The column has an exposed type of `bigint`, so it is rounded down to zero.

Clearly there can't really be zero distinct values when the range contains a non-zero numbers of rows.

One can only hope these discrepancies are cleared up at some stage; though it's hard to imagine exactly what that might look like without a potentially breaking change of data type, extending also to [`sys.dm_db_stats_histogram`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-stats-histogram-transact-sql) (available on SQL Server 2016 and later).

As for what you do about it, if you are convinced this is not just a display issue and is actually causing poor estimations, you should report it as a regression.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the root cause of bad sampled statistics may in fact be a bug with the statistics engine itself. I've added my own post here trying to describe what I think I've found - [Possible missing step in sampled statistics generation?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/323571/possible-missing-step-in-sampled-statistics-generation). In essence, DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS is only ever representative of the sample size - be it 1% or 100% - leading AVG_RANGE_ROWS to be extrapolated too far in the other direction to compensate. We can work around it ahead of time by swapping existing statistics to full scan but that doesn't really help us with statistics created on-the-fly...

EDIT - I mean... if we were in fullscan mode we'd always have non-zero DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS where AVG_RANGE_ROWS > 1, right? I suppose sample are always less accurate, even if they shouldn't be quite as innaccurate as they are currently, so even if sampled were *more* accurate than they are currently I suspect we'd still have the possibility of a histogram like the one above...